# PHP: Get value from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP variable that when I echo it will display an array that looks like this:

My Variable:

```
echo $mayVariable;
```

displays:

```
{"data":[{"id":"4756756575","name":"David","url":"https:\/\/www.somesite.com"}],"page":false}
```

I need to get the value from `id` within that array.

So I tried this:

```
echo $mayVariable[0]['id'];
```

But this doesn't give me anything.

I also tried:

```
echo $mayVariable['data']['id'];
```

and still I don't get anything in the echo...

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `JSON` is an object array after decode it generally.

```
$json = '{"data":[{"id":"4756756575","name":"David","url":"https:\/\/www.somesite.com"}],"page":false}';

$arr = json_decode($json);

echo $arr->data[0]->id;//4756756575
```

If you use `true` as second parameter then:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

echo $arr['data'][0]['id'];//4756756575
```